# Who is the best Partner for AD Kog'Maw?

Tags: league-of-legends

I like laning with Alistar because of his heal and knock-ups/knock-backs, but I have also heard that Janna or Sona are great partners to lane with. Who do you think is the best laning partner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nunu and Kog'maw were a popular combination from the IEM tournaments (Kiev/Hanover) for American teams.
The combination works well because Kog'maw and Nunu can maximize the slow effects of their abilities as well as the movement speed, attack speed buffs and increased range.

Nunu can sit by and land an ice ball so Kog'maw can attack the enemy from afar without being threatened. The combo also allows for strong ganks/escapes from allied or enemy junglers, respectively.

In this above link, we can see American Team Curse vs American Team TeamSolomid in IEM Hanover.
Curse is sporting the Kog'maw/Nunu combination and this is one example of the pair working successfully.

Comment: Great answer, I really wish more people would reference professional play.

Answer (score 1):

Nunu's Blood Boil is a HUGE buff to Kog'maw. So consider him.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your situation, sona is best if you are going against another support and ad carry who will give you trouble and hurt you a lot. Janna is great with her shield if you are aggressive enough and she is skilled enough.

I personally think janna is the best because her shield gives so much bonus AD and her knock up sided with her slow and shield along with kogmaws speed + range + slow it stands a good chance to kill a champion.

However Lulu has entered the game and with her passive sided with the shield kogmaw could deal a lot of damage with Lulu's e and passive

Answer (score 1):

Any champ with strong CC are good candidates for supporting KogMaw and all of them are viable depending who the enemy team has that are good at diving Kogmaw and your team for protecting kogmaw.  Consider that in IEM Gamescom, TSM ran against CLG a team comp that was Kogmaw, Alistar bot, AP Janna mid, Trundle in jungle.  Those 3 champs do outstanding in keeping any enemy from getting close to Kogmaw.  The bottom line is to make sure your team is ready and able to give you the protection kogmaw needs.

So really, look at who can support through utility and they are all viable.  Trying to not include some already mentioned:

Shen - aoe taunt and ult

Zilean - second life and speed buff/debuff

Kayle- heal/move speed and invulnerable to kill something free for a few seconds

Morgana - immune to all CC and reduce magic damage

Leona - two types of hard stuns and an immobilize

Maokai - damage reduction, immobilize, knockback

Rammus - taunt and knockback

Fiddlesticks - Fear, silence, and ult can even be used to keep players away from Kogmaw

Nautilus - again lots of immobilize, stun, knockup, pull, slows

I think anyone can extrapolate from this.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an opinion, but Nunu with blood Boil or Janna with Eye of the Storm give him the added AD/AS to get through his pretty dreadful early game. There is no real fact to this question though.

Answer (score 0):

I find Alistar is actually a suitable match for Kog'maw. He doesn't have the attack speed buff of nunu or the shield of janna, but he offers other benefits that make him a preferable choice. The CC in the form of pulverize and headbutt are essential in winning your lane or keeping the carry alive. On the topic of keeping Kog alive, Alistar boasts a heal that has a reduced cooldown rate every time an enemy is killed (minions included). He also does moderate damage that can be devastating to the rival AD carry that would likely be in the lane against you. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

nunu is best with kogmaw against sustain lane BUT janna + alistar are still the best supports to protect kogmaw away from dmg/CC